# helm error: release requires a rollback before it can be upgraded

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, fluxcd

In my cluster Im using [weave flux](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux) along with their flux-helm-operator to manage my cluster the gitops way.

However, when I make a change to the chart at flux git repository, I often come across the following error msg:

```
ts=2019-09-25T11:54:37.604506452Z caller=chartsync.go:328 component=chartsync
warning="unable to proceed with release" 
resource=mychart:helmrelease/mychart release=mychart
err="release requires a rollback before it can be upgraded (FAILED)"
```

Im not sure what does it mean in helm, but anyway, I am not supposed to run any helm command since the releases are managed by flux so I am wondering what is the correct way to deal with this error on production

(besides deleting the release and waiting for flux to recreate it)

A well-explained answer will be very much accepted, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Let's dive into the code of [`helm-operator`](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator)

Warning `unable to proceed with release` arises after [`GetUpgradableRelease`](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator/blob/801c64c5fde1e0aa228e5012f2f9514311bff6a9/pkg/chartsync/chartsync.go#L325)

> ```
>     // GetUpgradableRelease returns a release if the current state of it
>     // allows an upgrade, a descriptive error if it is not allowed, or
>     // nil if the release does not exist.
> ```

It returns error `release requires a rollback before it can be upgraded` if release has `Status_FAILED` state (see [release.go#89](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator/blob/68b5f64c1ba2a4859581a82fa6b16bbc313c02f6/pkg/release/release.go#L89) )

## `UNHEALTHY` state blocks release

As `flux` developers [mentioned in #2265](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/issues/2265), there is no way to roll to `UNHEALTHY` state.

> This is not a bug but I can see where your expectation is coming from.
>
> Flux will only move healthy releases forward, one of the reasons for this is to ensure we do not end up in a loop of failure, the `--force` flag is thus not intended to be used to force the upgrade of an unhealthy resource (you should use the [rollback feature](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/blob/8292179855e15370fb3d3b03135a61b54f00ae42/site/helm-integration.md#rollbacks) for this) but was developed to make it possible to upgrade charts with e.g. backwards incompatible changes (changes on immutable fields for example, which require a resource to be removed first, see [#1760](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/pull/1760)).
>
> **Conclusion:** the `forceUpgrade` is honoured, but can not be used to force the upgrade of a release in an `UNHEALTHY` state.

## [Rollback](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/blob/8292179855e15370fb3d3b03135a61b54f00ae42/site/helm-integration.md#rollbacks)

As author recommends, you should use [`rollback`](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux/blob/8292179855e15370fb3d3b03135a61b54f00ae42/site/helm-integration.md#rollbacks) feature

> From time to time a release made by the Helm operator may fail, it is possible to automate the rollback of a failed release by setting `.spec.rollback.enable` to true on the HelmRelease resource.
>
> ```
> Note: a successful rollback of a Helm chart containing a StatefulSet resource is known to be tricky, and one of the main reasons automated rollbacks are not enabled by default for all HelmReleases. Verify a manual rollback of your Helm chart does not cause any problems before enabling it.
> ```
>
> When enabled, the Helm operator will detect a faulty upgrade and perform a rollback, it will not attempt a new upgrade unless it detects a change in values and/or the chart.

```
apiVersion: flux.weave.works/v1beta1
kind: HelmRelease
# metadata: ...
spec:
  # Listed values are the defaults.
  rollback:
    # If set, will perform rollbacks for this release.
    enable: false
    # If set, will force resource update through delete/recreate if
    # needed.
    force: false
    # Prevent hooks from running during rollback.
    disableHooks: false
    # Time in seconds to wait for any individual Kubernetes operation.
    timeout: 300
    # If set, will wait until all Pods, PVCs, Services, and minimum
    # number of Pods of a Deployment are in a ready state before
    # marking the release as successful. It will wait for as long
    # as the set timeout.
    wait: false
```

Comment: fair enough, then how should i handle such cases?

Comment: Also, check pls rollback feature, explained in updated answer

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, ill try it tomorrow to see if it solves my problem and let you know the result, thanks

Comment: Hi @EfratLevitan glad that tip helped